# When is -の used for a question

Tags: meaning, usage, conversations

When is -の used for a question and what is the exact meaning

Context:

(nj) = (Native Japanese speaker)

- (njs): 学校に行くの?
- (me): いいえ、学校は行きません。
- (njs): 自分でやるの？
- (me): 自分やります。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

の is a more casual/friendly way to ask a question when ですか or Vますか would feel a little bit too polite. You can think of it as ん(の)ですか without the ですか part. For instance:

> 学校に行きますか？
>   学校に行くの？

These sentences have the exact same meaning but the first one is much more formal. Note that 学校に行くか is a bit harsher and more rarely used.

Also, *Nounですか* becomes *Nounなの？* You need the な otherwise it means "the one of [Noun]?". You will also need the な if you are connecting a な-adjective.

> 簡単ですか。
>   簡単なの？