# Difference between か, の and のか

Tags: particles, sentence-final-particles

To ask, for example, "Have you already finished doing homework?", is there any difference in using か, の and のか?

> もう宿題を終えたか？
>   もう宿題を終えたの？
>   もう宿題を終えたのか？

I'm a little bit confused about how many different question particles are there in Japanese and the difference between them (which are said by men, which ones by women, which are stronger in emphasis, etc.). Is there any site where this kind of things are explained?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: There is no exact question that this is a duplicate of, but I think you can find most of your answers in other questions. See a bunch of questions on this topic:
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54792/word-choose-between-%E3%81%8B-and-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33162/difference-between-%E3%81%8B-and-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/51894/when-is-%E3%81%AE-used-for-a-question
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11914/is-ending-question-sentences-with-%E3%81%AE-really-feminine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word choose between か and のか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54792/word-choose-between-%e3%81%8b-and-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8b)

Comment: Maybe add “no particle” to the list?

Comment: 私なら「（もう）宿題終わった？」っていうかな・・